# Android simple gallery custom

Tags: android, timer, gallery, slideshow, image

As the title I need a little help to my university project that I'm working on. 
I have to make an Activity in android that given a set of images run a slideshow with timer. This activity is divided into three parts:

- the above: a button to start/pause the slideshow of images
- central part: the current image displayed in the middle screen
- underneath: three images that represent, respectively, the previous image, the current and the next slideshow.

Also if it is carried out a swipe on the middle one has to go to the previous or next depending on the direction of the swipe.
I have already made ​​the layout xml and the acitivity. Can someone help me, maybe even in the slightest? Many thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#000000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button_stop"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_notes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/text_view_desc"
        android:text="@string/default_notes" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_current"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class Slideshow extends Activity{  
        private Button startstop;
        public ImageView ivdiplayed, ivprevious, ivcurrent, ivnext;
        boolean isPlaying = true; //true=play | false=stop

        @Override  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.slideshow);

            //imageview
            ivdiplayed = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            ivprevious = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_previous);
            ivcurrent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_current);
            ivnext = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_next);

            //play/stop button
            startstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_stop);
            startstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(isPlaying){
                        startstop.setText(getString(R.string.button_stop));
                        isPlaying=false;
                    }
                    else{
                        startstop.setText(getString(R.string.button_play));
                        isPlaying=true;
                    } 
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)? This will make it easier to slide images.
You can replace your middle (main) image with a ViewPager. Here are steps:

First- we edit page layout [notice the ViewPager]
**mainLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#000000" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_start_stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/button_stop"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
 
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pagr"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_notes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:contentDescription="@string/text_view_desc"
    android:text="@string/default_notes" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_view_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then we create our Image item view that will be shown in the ViewPager.
**imageitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imageItem"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:contentDescription="my mage" />
```

After That we need to create the adapter to handle these images within the ViewPager
**ImageAdapter.Java class**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

// list of images resources ids
private ArrayList<Integer> items;
private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> items) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    View v = null;
LayoutInflater vi = null;
   
    if (v == null) {
        vi = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.imageitem, null);
    }

    }

    // sets the image resource to our ImageView item
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageItem);
    imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position));

    // add the image to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((View) object);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Finally our MainActivity Class
**Slideshow.Java class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Slideshow extends Activity{ 
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ImageAdapter adapter;
    private Button startstop;
private Thread timerThread;
    public ImageView ivdiplayed, ivprevious, ivcurrent, ivnext;
    boolean isPlaying = true; //true=play | false=stop

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.slideshow);

    // Setup Images List
ArrayList<Integer> imageResources = new ArrayList<Integer>();
imageResources.add(R.drawable.image1);
imageResources.add(R.drawable.image2);
imageResources.add(R.drawable.image3); // etc.. add all images you got

// Initialize our timer thread
timerThread = new Thread(this);

        //Init our ViewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagr);

    //Init our Adapter and pass it the list of images
    adapter = new ImagesAdapter(this, imageResources);

    // Set the adapter to the view
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    ivprevious = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_previous);
        ivcurrent = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_current);
        ivnext = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_next);

    // To detect when image changes
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(position>0)// No images before
            ivprevious.setImageResource(imageResources.get(position-1));
                ivcurrent.setImageResource(imageResources.get(position-1));
        
        if(position<(imageResources.size()-1))// No images after
                ivnext.setImageResource(imageResources.get(position+1));
        }
    });

        //play/stop button
        startstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_stop);
        startstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isPlaying){
                    startstop.setText(getString(R.string.button_stop));
                    isPlaying=false;
                }
                else{
        /*Start our timer.. You can use AlarmManger, but I think this will do the trick*/
        timerThread.start();
                    startstop.setText(getString(R.string.button_play));
                    isPlaying=true;
                } 
            }
        });
    }

// Our Timer thread function
public void run() {
// The position of the current image shown in the ViewPager
int position;

while (isPlaying) { //condition to exit thread loop
//Get which image is selected in the ViewPager
position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    try {
// Time between each slide in MilliSeconds 
        Thread.sleep(1000);

// Move to next image if available OR go to first one
if(position<(imageResources.size()-1)){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position+1);
}else{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }            
}
}
}
```

Hope this helps you, There are a lot of better approaches for that but I think this is a simple and easy way to do it.
Also.. I didn't test it so you might need some minor fixes... sorry